# PostgreSQL: Trigger INSERT INTO SELECT from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will add a new row processed entry to a destination table each time a new row is created in the source table.

Step 1 Create destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.destination_table (
                          id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                          created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                          sale_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          product_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                          product_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                          url VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
                          shop_id VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                          user_id VARCHAR)
```

Step 2 Create trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION triger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.destination_table ( created_at, sale_id, product_id, product_name, url, shop_id, user_id)
 SELECT created_at,
        sale_id,
        product_id,
        product_name,
        split_part(url::text, '?'::text, 1) AS url,
        shop_id,
        ((((((((data #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) -> 'local_storage'::text) -> 'data'::text) #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) ->> 'user_id'::varchar AS user_id
   FROM source_table;
           RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

** The Select query inside function work normally when single running.

Step 3 Create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_records
     AFTER INSERT ON public.source_table
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE triger_function();
```

The problem is that Trigger does not work, which means it does not record new entries in the target table. Can't figure out where the error is.

Comment: 1 ) The problem is you did not read this [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) 2) The `SELECT` portion of the query  has no `WHERE` so you would be selecting all rows  from `source_table`. 3) You don't need the `SELECT` because if you had done 1) you would know that you have the newly entered values available as `NEW.*` e.g. `NEW.created_at, NEW.sale_id, NEW.product_id`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the NEW record in the trigger function to reference the newly inserted data instead of a select, i.e.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION triger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.destination_table ( created_at, sale_id, product_id, product_name, url, shop_id, user_id)
VALUES(NEW.created_at,
    NEW.sale_id,
    NEW.product_id,
    NEW.product_name,
    split_part(NEW.url::text, '?'::text, 1),
    NEW.shop_id,
    ((((((((NEW.data #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) -> 'local_storage'::text) -> 'data'::text) #>> '{}'::text[])::jsonb) ->> 'user_id'::varchar)
       RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```